# File Upload control HasFile always false, name is always Empty String, no update panel used

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a Details View that has a file upload field in it.  When I fill out the information and upload a file (I have tried multiple files ranging from 9k to 6.8MB) all of the information (text fields) submit fine, but the uploaded file is always returning a false when I check the HasFile and always returns String.Empty when I check the file name.

Am I doing something wrong?  The details view is in a Panel and **Not an Update Panel**

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server"
        Visible="false">
        <h4 runat="server" id="h2SubCaption">Person Details</h4>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="dvAssignment" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateRows="false" 
            Width="100%"
            SkinID="SampleDetailsView" 
            CssSelectorClass="PrettyDetailsView"
            DataKeyNames="guidMemberId"
            DefaultMode="Edit"
            OnItemUpdating="dvAssignment_ItemUpdating" 
            OnModeChanging="dvAssignment_ModeChanging"
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True" >  
<Fields>   
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nomination Letter">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileuploadNomination" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> .....
```

Code Behind:

```
        FileUpload _nomination = (FileUpload)dv.FindControl("fileuploadNomination");
    byte[] nominationByte = null;
    if (_nomination.FileName != string.Empty)
        nominationByte = _nomination.FileBytes;
    //if(_nomination.HasFile)
    //nominationByte = _nomination.FileBytes;
```

**EDIT**
I added a Page_Load call and it looks as if the page is posting back when I click the Auto Generated Update Button for the DetailsView.  This postback is probably clearing out my FileUpload field.  Any ideas on how to get around it?

**Edit #2** I have now put an update panel around the DetailsView and set the postback trigger the DetailsView (see below) and it still is not working, it seems to be clearing the upload control prior to submitting.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server"
            Visible="false">
            <h4 runat="server" id="h2SubCaption">Person Details</h4>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="dvAssignment" 
                runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateRows="false" 
                Width="100%"
                SkinID="SampleDetailsView" 
                CssSelectorClass="PrettyDetailsView"
                DataKeyNames="guidMemberId"
                DefaultMode="Edit"
                OnItemUpdating="dvAssignment_ItemUpdating" 
                OnModeChanging="dvAssignment_ModeChanging"
                AutoGenerateEditButton="True" >
                <FieldHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" />
                <Fields>
```

```
                            <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileuploadNomination" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView >       
            </asp:Panel>
         </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="dvAssignment" /> 
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Gridview Code as requested**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvQuality" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Width="100%"
        DataKeyNames="guidMemberId"
        CssSelectorClass="PrettyGridView"
        SkinID="SampleGridView"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvQuality_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        onrowdatabound="gvQuality_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Select" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

a few bound fields are after this (first name, last name, etc)

```
protected void gvQuality_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Guid guidMemberId = (Guid)gvQuality.SelectedDataKey.Values["guidMemberId"];
    PortalDataContext db = new PortalDataContext(AuthenticatedUser.ConnectionString);
    h2SubCaption.InnerText = "Update Person";
    dvAssignment.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);

    dvAssignment.DataSource = LINQ Query Here
    dvAssignment.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Are you rebinding the DetailsView on each postback?

Comment: I am only binding the DetailsView on the SelectedIndexChanged of the Gridview.  The Gridview has an edit link, which fires the DetailsView to bind and become visible.

Comment: I am doing this same thing in one of my project and I have an imagebutton that triggers the upload I can't see one in your code and my button's CausesValidation is set to false, not sure if it is importan though.

Comment: I am trying to use the built in Update link to submit the DetailsView

Comment: i was solved same issue using below link http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/simpleajaxupload.asp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everyone, Thanks for all of the help but I figured it out.  I had to set the `Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data`.

Here is the code for it to work!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
}
```

Comment: That is such a great answer. I had FileUpload on an UpdatePanel with full postback, but it was not working the first time someone hits the page.
But now it is!
That would have taken days to find that solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is a dumb answer but I usually use on gridviews the selectedindexchanging to capture current row values.  Have you tried that instead of the selectedindexchanged?

Comment: No I have not tried that, I used the Changed event because I need the databinding of the DetailsView to happen after the index of the GridView has changed, not in the process of it.  I don't think this is the issue though.

Comment: Ok I created a test page no gridview just a Detailsview and tested out the code you have and on dvAssignment_ItemUpdating it runs perfect.  So it definatly has to do with your gridview something there is not letting it work correctly.  Do you mind putting code snippet of your gridview so I can test with that?

Comment: I have added some snippets of my GridView, it is very basic

Comment: Saw you figured it out, awesome I've seen that aswell in PHP if you don't set the form "multipart/form-data" it doesn't recognize the fileupload, didn't know that was needed in .net aswell...I guess we all learn something new everyday huh.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
Request.Files[0] get the upload file

Comment: Index was out of range.  Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: I wrote it in my save function which is called from dvAssignment_ItemUpdating

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only have one `<form>` on the same page.