# FileUpload control HasFile fails but file is actually available

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

My file upload control is not part of an UpdatePanel. It just resides in a `asp:panel`. When I step through the debugger I see the FileName property properly populated, FileBytes,PostedFile etc. but HasFile alone is false. I am at my wits end trying to figure this out because the FileName property has the expected value but HasFile is false. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183910/file-upload-control-hasfile-always-false-name-is-always-empty-string-no-update?rq=1) did not help either!

```
<asp:Panel id="AddEditReport" runat="server" Visible="false" style= "display:inline;" >
 <asp:HiddenField ID="ReportField" runat="server" Value="Report" />
 <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>Title:</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Report" runat="server" Width="342px"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td valign="top"><asp:Label ID="Description_Label" runat="server" Text="Header Description" /></td>
          <td><asp:TextBox  TextMode="MultiLine" ID="Description" runat="server" Width="342px" height="250px" AutoPostBack="false"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="DisplayOrder_Label" runat="server" Text="Display Order" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_DisplayOrder" runat="server" Width="42px" MaxLength="2" AutoPostBack="false"/>            
        </td>          
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="FileUploader_Label" Text="Copy of file: "/></td>
          <td><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_Report" runat="server"/></td>
      </tr>
 </table></asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel ID="Button" runat="server">
    <asp:Button id="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="SaveButton_clicked"/>
    <asp:button id="Back" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="BackButton_clicked" UseSubmitBehavior="False"></asp:button><%
int id;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[QuerystringID]))
{
    id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[QuerystringID]);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReportRepository.GetReportById(id).FilePath))
    {
%>      <a  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this heading?')"  href="FileUpload.aspx?id=<%=id.ToString()%>&delete=true" target="_self">
         <input type="button" value="Delete Heading"/>
    </a>
 <% 
    }
   }
  %></asp:Panel>
```

This is my entire page.

The code behind snippet where the HasFile fails:

```
if (FileUpload_Report.HasFile)/*Fails always*/
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileUpload_Report.FileName);
    // First add the report to get the ID.
    ReportRepository.Add(report);
    // Then update with the created filepath.
    report.FilePath = PathRoot + @"/" + GetFilename(report) + fileInfo.Extension;
    // Update the old report with a deleteddate.
    ReportRepository.Update(oldReport);
    ReportRepository.Update(report);
    FileUpload_Report.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(PathRoot) + "\\" + GetFilename(report) + fileInfo.Extension);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: why dont you put the FileUpload in an update panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if the file is empty [ 0 KB ] then it will return false as well. There has to be something in the file in order for .HasFile to acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and let me know if it works:

```
if (FileUpload_Report.PostedFile == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileUpload_Report.PostedFile.FileName) || FileUpload_Report.PostedFile.InputStream == null) { 
   // File Doesn't Exist
} Else {
   // File Exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the AddEditReport panel is visible before SaveButton_clicked is executed. I'm just saying that because I noticed you've got it starting out at Visible="false" and who knows what else your code is doing.

The upload control will lose its state if something like this happens

1. Event somewhere sets AddEditReport.Visible = true
2. User uses the file upload control
3. Event somewhere sets AddEditReport.Visible = false
4. User clicks the save button
5. Upload control loses its state